# Spring Cloud Gateway & oauth token

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

getting started with spring-cloud-gateway and I have 2 paths setup through all configuration. The issue I’m running into is that both of these paths require an oauth bearer token to be able to access. I’ve spent days trying to configure this. Is there a relatively easy way to integrate spring-oauth to get a token and add it to the headers before the call to either of the uri ? I’ve also tried a custom filter that in theory would get the token and modify the headers but I was unable to retrieve the token. Any examples would be appreciated.

Configuration I tried:

```
spring:
  main.web-application-type: reactive
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-app:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          my-app:
            token-uri: https://xxxxxxxx.com/oauth2/token
```

Security  Config class:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.oauth2Client().and().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
      ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
      ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
        new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
        new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
  }
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication(
exclude = {
  SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class GatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

POM:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.72.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: are you giving us a gift like a program code for what you tried?

Comment: @Numichi I've updated the post with what I've tried.